# Java MVC para validar datos de los controles

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en `MVC` y quisiera saber donde se valida que los controles de la vista tengan información.
Por ejemplo, para sumar dos números en el siguiente ejemplo, ¿dónde valido que `txtNumero1` y `txtNumero2` de una vista no estén vacíos?

- Modelo :

  ```
    public class Modelo {
        // Variables
        private int valor1;
        private int valor2;

        public Modelo() {
        }

        public void set_valor1(int val) {
            this.valor1 = val;
        }

        public int get_valor1() {
            return this.valor1;
        }

        public void set_valor2(int val) {
            this.valor2 = val;
        }

        public int get_valor2() {
            return this.valor2;
        }

        public int sumar() {
            return this.valor1 + this.valor2;
        }
    }
  ```
- Vista :

Tiene una caja de texto (`txtNumero1`), una caja de texto (`txtNumero2`), una caja de texto (`txtResultado`) y un botón `btnSumar`.

- Controlador :

  ```
    public class controlador implements ActionListener{

        private vista vista;
        private Modelo modelo;


        public controlador( vista vista , modelo modelo){
            this.vista = vista;
            this.modelo = modelo;
            this.vista.cmdsumar.addActionListener(this);
        }


        public void iniciar_vista(){
            vista.setTitle( "Sumar" );
            vista.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            modelo.set_valor1(Integer.valueOf( vista.txtNumero1.getText() ) );
            modelo.set_valor2( Integer.valueOf( vista.txtNumero2.getText() )          vista.txtResultado.setText(String.valueOf(modelo.sumar()) );
        }
    }
  ```

¿Desde dónde podría validar? ¿Desde el modelo, desde el controlador o desde ambos?

Answer (score 1):

Según yo lo mas correcto seria validar en el controlador ya que es quien se encarga de procesar los datos por así decirlo la vista únicamente los representa y el modelo pues es la plantilla de los objetos que vas a usar por tanto la parte fuerte para programar o lo mas robusto por lo regular es el controlador  y sería mas conveniente validar allí

Comment: Podria ser en el controlador: private bool validar(){ if (vista.txtNumber.getText.equals("")) JOptionPane("Falta número1")return false.....} e invocar a valdiar desde el actionPerformed del controller?

Comment: oooo ya  entendí lo que quieres lograr,   bueno  ya que tu ejemplo es bastante sencillo sera mas fácil validar en el  evento, es decir  manejas un botón  para desencadenar  el evento para  sumar no?  entonces seria más fácil validar  en ese trozo de código que te genera el entorno.

ese if que comentaste arriba  colocalo en el evento del  boton de esta forma si tienes algo que sumar efectuas las operaciones  si no no tendria caso desperdiciar recursos por muy minimos que sean

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a usar validaciones de este tipo yo aprovecharía las anotaciones JSR-349 (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349). Por ejemplo que no estén vacías:

```
public class Modelo {
    //Variables
    @NotEmpty
    private int valor1;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private int valor2;
   

    public Modelo(){}

    public void set_valor1(int val){
        this.valor1=val;
    }

    public int get_valor1(){
        return this.valor1;
    }

    public void set_valor2(int val){
        this.valor2=val;
    }

    public int get_valor2(){
        return this.valor2;
    }

    public int sumar(){
        return  this.valor1 + this.valor2;
       
    }
  }
```

De esta forma validarías el bean completo, además veo que usas struts, personalmente prefiero Spring MVC, para mí es mucho más potente. Te dejo un ejemplo de como se usaría:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sumar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sumar(@Valid Modelo modelo, BindingResult result) {
        // lógica
    }
}
```

Con la anotación @Valid, de forma automática realiza la validación de los datos de entrada. De esta forma no te tienes que construir métodos específicos para todas las validaciones.

Espero haberte ayudado en algo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristian, yo recien comienzo en un entorno desktop, Para desktop como lo ves?

Comment: Me parece que el uso de estas anotaciones es esta aplicación es como utilizar una bazuka para eliminar una araña.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente cuando hablamos de MVC nos referimos a una aplicación web. Si estas comenzando con este paradigma te recomiendo aprender Spring MVC con videos de InfiniteSkills de Kevin Bowersox, estan en inglés, pero es de lo mejor.

Cuando te refieres a validación, se entienden dos cosas:

1. Validación del Objeto (Puedes validar en el controlador usando Spring)
2. Validación de campos vía JSP (Puedes usar HibernateAnnotations o JS)

La combinación de ambos hace mas robusta tu aplicación.

Cristian te da una muestra de lo potente que puede ser Spring.

Saludos